# Select objects in offline .map in android in mapsforge

Tags: android, dictionary, offline, graphhopper, mapsforge

I have developed an android application that uses the mapsforge library to display the offline map and the offline map is in .map of osm map of my area. Now I need to get all the hospitals location in my map so that I can calculate the route to the hospitals using graphhopper? Can Anybody suggest how to select the hospitals from my map or Do I need to use any other methods?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to store all the POIs somewhere else or use internet connection to e.g. the overpass turbo API. GraphHopper is just about routing and mapsforge data can also only be used for displaying not searching (sadly).

Comment: Can you please point me to any suitable example on Turbo API and how it can be used in android for my suitation.